# History search possible in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I thinking to create one function/procedure/query, what help me to do history.

Example:

My database give minutely fresh data.
If I have one year data. And my customer looking data more than 1 month range that case every 30 minute give me back to the maximum, ( that is 360 values ). If the customer range less than 1 month that case minutely give me back the data ( that is 43200 values ). And this function I built in Delphi software.

This is possible? I don't have any code yet to give help.

Try to give some example:

Table:

| ID | cost | weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 250 | 300 |
| 2 | 200 | 250 | 300 |
| 3 | 200 | 250 | 300 |
| 4 | 200 | 250 | 300 |
| 5 | 200 | 250 | 300 |

The ID have foreign key with another table Timestamp. And minutely comes one new row.
I like to create 30 min groups. The 30 min groups give me back only that 30 values maximum. The minute of corse come back all because minutely 1 row comes.

If i insert this query my software just need to run the query the software made all of the rest.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Please consider providing some examples.

Comment: In order to search history (or anything) you need tables containing the data to search.  There's a [Temporal Table](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables)  extension to postgreSQL. You might be able to use that, or you might need to add history tables to your application, and write code to insert rows to those tables whenever you need to record old data. It might be possible to do your search with just one "function/procedure/query", but your first step is to record the history.